# Does Windows Admin Center have a plugin system?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, sysadmin

Does the [Windows Admin Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/understand/windows-admin-center) support writing plugins? I can't find a lot of information on it, and I was wondering if it had a plugin system that I could write C# .NET applications for. I want to be able to get information about IIS application pools and display them in the Windows Admin Center.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Windows Management Center"?

Comment: @EBGreen Sorry I meant Windows Admin Center. I updated my question with the correct name of the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/understand/what-is) link you can. There is even a link to the SDK. I realize that link only answers are rightly frowned upon, but in this case that is the answer. Yes you can and here is where MS says so...

Comment: Well that is horrible, I was looking for Window Management Framework plugins and not for plugging into the UI component Windows Admin Center. Thank you for googling that for me :(